# A Javascript error occurred in the process: The Application could not be started at Socket

Tags: spring-boot, electron, electron-builder, launch4j

I am trying to trigger a java backend process from an electron app using "child_process.spawn" . The java backend process is a .exe generated using launch4J. The application runs without any issues in dev mode but the packaged electron application keeps throwing this error when run in a different setup.

[image]

This is what the code to trigger the backend process looks like

```
function invokeJavaBackend() {
  const javaBackendProcess = spawn(exePath, { shell: true });
  javaBackendProcess.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    win && win.webContents.send("java-backend-response", data.toString());
    log.info(data.toString());
  });

  javaBackendProcess.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
    log.info(data);
    setTimeout(function () {
      app.exit();
    }, 1000);
    throw new Error("The Application could not be started");
  });

  javaBackendProcess.on("close", (code) => {
    log.info("Java Backend child process exited with code ", code);
  });
}
```

Comment: You have a `log.info(data)` in that error handler. Does it give you any information (or does passing `data` to that `new Error` show anything useful)?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I am using electron-log and as per the documentation(https://github.com/megahertz/electron-log) the log file should have been created at %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\{app name}\logs\ but I do not see any file created there


`const log = require('electron-log');
log.transports.file.level = 'info';
log.transports.file.resolvePath = () => __dirname + "/logs/log.log";`